# Android how to identify audio/video from xml?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, rss

I am working to read audio, video news from rss feed. How do I identify whether that rss is for news reader or audio or video?

This is a video feed: `http://feeds.cbsnews.com/CBSNewsVideo` and this is text feed: `http://indiatoday.feedsportal.com/c/33614/f/589699/index.rss`

By opening this, we can understand whether it is video or text.
How can we come to know, while parsing this XML file?

EDIT: Xml for http://feeds.cbsnews.com/CBSNewsVideo

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="/~d/styles/rss2enclosuresfull.xsl"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~d/styles/itemcontent.css"?><rss xmlns:s="http://www.cbsnews.com" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" version="2.0">
            <channel>
                <link>http://www.cbsnews.com</link>
                <title>More from CBS News Video - CBS News</title>
                <language>en-us</language>
                <ttl>5</ttl>
                <description>Read the latest CBS News Video headlines on CBS News, covering news stories, videos and pictures of world and US news, as well as news in politics, health, sports and business.</description>

                <copyright>Your (optional) copyright message</copyright>
                  <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 08:54:39 EDT</pubDate>
                    <atom10:link xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/CBSNewsVideo" /><feedburner:info uri="cbsnewsvideo" /><atom10:link xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="hub" href="http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/" /><media:copyright>Your (optional) copyright message</media:copyright><media:thumbnail url="http://www.myserver.com/podcastlogo.jpg" /><media:keywords>Type,in,keywords,separated,by,spaces,that,can,help,listeners,locate,your,podcast,when,searching,with,iTunes</media:keywords><image><link>http://www.cbsnews.com/</link><url>http://wwwimage.cbsnews.com/common/images/v2/logo_cbsnews_small.gif</url><title>CBSNews.com</title></image><feedburner:feedFlare href="http://add.my.yahoo.com/rss?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.cbsnews.com%2FCBSNewsVideo" src="http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/my/addtomyyahoo4.gif">Subscribe with My Yahoo!</feedburner:feedFlare><feedburner:feedFlare href="http://www.newsgator.com/ngs/subscriber/subext.aspx?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.cbsnews.com%2FCBSNewsVideo" src="http://www.newsgator.com/images/ngsub1.gif">Subscribe with NewsGator</feedburner:feedFlare><feedburner:feedFlare href="http://www.netvibes.com/subscribe.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.cbsnews.com%2FCBSNewsVideo" src="http://www.netvibes.com/img/add2netvibes.gif">Subscribe with Netvibes</feedburner:feedFlare><feedburner:feedFlare href="http://fusion.google.com/add?feedurl=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.cbsnews.com%2FCBSNewsVideo" src="http://buttons.googlesyndication.com/fusion/add.gif">Subscribe with Google</feedburner:feedFlare><feedburner:feedFlare href="http://www.pageflakes.com/subscribe.aspx?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.cbsnews.com%2FCBSNewsVideo" src="http://www.pageflakes.com/ImageFile.ashx?instanceId=Static_4&amp;fileName=ATP_blu_91x17.gif">Subscribe with Pageflakes</feedburner:feedFlare><feedburner:feedFlare href="http://www.live.com/?add=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.cbsnews.com%2FCBSNewsVideo" src="http://tkfiles.storage.msn.com/x1piYkpqHC_35nIp1gLE68-wvzLZO8iXl_JMledmJQXP-XTBOLfmQv4zhj4MhcWEJh_GtoBIiAl1Mjh-ndp9k47If7hTaFno0mxW9_i3p_5qQw">Subscribe with Live.com</feedburner:feedFlare><feedburner:feedFlare href="http://odeo.com/listen/subscribe?feed=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.cbsnews.com%2FCBSNewsVideo" src="http://odeo.com/img/badge-channel-black.gif">Subscribe with ODEO</feedburner:feedFlare><feedburner:feedFlare href="http://www.podnova.com/add.srf?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.cbsnews.com%2FCBSNewsVideo" src="http://www.podnova.com/img_chicklet_podnova.gif">Subscribe with Podnova</feedburner:feedFlare><item>

                            <title>Video: Drowning: The real signs a swimmer is in danger</title>  
                      <link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/ZQzIjwZR3Xg/</link>
                        <description>CBS News' Don Dahler reports on drowning -- the second most common cause of accidental death in children aged 14 and younger -- and how to prevent it by knowing what drowning really looks like.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=ZQzIjwZR3Xg:Fa5H9AQULHc:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=ZQzIjwZR3Xg:Fa5H9AQULHc:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=ZQzIjwZR3Xg:Fa5H9AQULHc:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=ZQzIjwZR3Xg:Fa5H9AQULHc:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=ZQzIjwZR3Xg:Fa5H9AQULHc:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/ZQzIjwZR3Xg" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148435n</guid>                   
                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 08:54:39 EDT</pubDate>    
                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148435n</feedburner:origLink></item>
                    <item>
                            <title>Video: Russian President Putin and wife announce divorce</title>
                      <link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/aOQ7ONwOxT8/</link>
                        <description>After years of speculation, Russian President Vladimir Putin and his wife announced they are getting a divorce, less than two months shy of their 30th wedding anniversary. Norah O'Donnell reports.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=aOQ7ONwOxT8:m3EGbztX7-k:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=aOQ7ONwOxT8:m3EGbztX7-k:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=aOQ7ONwOxT8:m3EGbztX7-k:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=aOQ7ONwOxT8:m3EGbztX7-k:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=aOQ7ONwOxT8:m3EGbztX7-k:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/aOQ7ONwOxT8" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148430n</guid>         
                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 08:52:58 EDT</pubDate>     
                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148430n</feedburner:origLink></item>

                    <item>

                            <title>Video: Headlines: Defamation suit filed over "Bag Men" headline</title>        
                <link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/sbd4yNXRaJk/</link>
                        <description>"CBS This Morning" takes a look at some of the day's headlines from around the globe.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=sbd4yNXRaJk:7kbI768YfDI:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=sbd4yNXRaJk:7kbI768YfDI:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=sbd4yNXRaJk:7kbI768YfDI:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=sbd4yNXRaJk:7kbI768YfDI:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=sbd4yNXRaJk:7kbI768YfDI:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/sbd4yNXRaJk" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148434n</guid>            
                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 08:10:35 EDT</pubDate>     
                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148434n</feedburner:origLink></item>
                    <item>
                            <title>Video: Prince Philip back in the hospital for surgery</title>
                        <link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/KkcbZxeHEc4/</link>
                        <description>In Britain, Queen Elizabeth II's 92-year-old husband Prince Philip is back in the hospital. He'll be undergoing surgery, and is expected to remain hospitalized for up to two weeks. Charlie D'Agata reports from London.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=KkcbZxeHEc4:EESGGAnvV80:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=KkcbZxeHEc4:EESGGAnvV80:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=KkcbZxeHEc4:EESGGAnvV80:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=KkcbZxeHEc4:EESGGAnvV80:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=KkcbZxeHEc4:EESGGAnvV80:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/KkcbZxeHEc4" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148433n</guid>             
                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 08:10:33 EDT</pubDate>
                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148433n</feedburner:origLink></item>
<item>

                            <title>Video: Jobs report preview: Why Wall Street will be watching</title>
<link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/OlFkxwyPgQY/</link>
                        <description>Wall Street investors will be watching the jobs report after a turbulent week in the markets. Anthony Mason takes a look at the importance of this report.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=OlFkxwyPgQY:GiiVhaE-SrA:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=OlFkxwyPgQY:GiiVhaE-SrA:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=OlFkxwyPgQY:GiiVhaE-SrA:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=OlFkxwyPgQY:GiiVhaE-SrA:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=OlFkxwyPgQY:GiiVhaE-SrA:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/OlFkxwyPgQY" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148432n</guid>
                     <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 08:10:31 EDT</pubDate>


                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148432n</feedburner:origLink></item>
<item>

                            <title>Video: Cyber security may take center stage at U.S., China summit</title>
<link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/sSonCH7od9s/</link>
                        <description>The relationship between the United States and China will be tested this weekend in California, as President Obama and China's new president, Xi Jinping, will discuss economic issues, North Korea and particularly, cyber security will come to the fore. Chip Reid reports.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=sSonCH7od9s:oPEMyGTRJyk:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=sSonCH7od9s:oPEMyGTRJyk:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=sSonCH7od9s:oPEMyGTRJyk:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=sSonCH7od9s:oPEMyGTRJyk:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=sSonCH7od9s:oPEMyGTRJyk:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/sSonCH7od9s" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148431n</guid>
                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 08:10:29 EDT</pubDate>

                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148431n</feedburner:origLink></item>

                    <item>
                            <title>Video: Tracking tropical storm Andrea</title>
 <link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/qAPkZQEXNK4/</link>
                        <description>Meteorologist Jeff Berardelli of CBS Miami station WFOR-TV reports the latest on the storm's movements and where it's expected to hit next.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=qAPkZQEXNK4:gPfH39D9Ccg:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=qAPkZQEXNK4:gPfH39D9Ccg:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=qAPkZQEXNK4:gPfH39D9Ccg:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=qAPkZQEXNK4:gPfH39D9Ccg:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=qAPkZQEXNK4:gPfH39D9Ccg:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/qAPkZQEXNK4" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148427n</guid>

                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 07:53:16 EDT</pubDate>
                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148427n</feedburner:origLink></item>

                    <item> 
                            <title>Video: Tropical storm Andrea threatens East Coast</title>                                   
                        <link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/-fOcL8rqkR4/</link>
                        <description>The first named storm of the Atlantic hurricane season now threatens the entire East Coast. It has already flooded parts of Florida and at least eight tornadoes were reported as the storm hit the Gulf Coast. Justin Lock, of CBS affiliate WCSC, reports.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=-fOcL8rqkR4:oufe73J_G-M:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=-fOcL8rqkR4:oufe73J_G-M:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=-fOcL8rqkR4:oufe73J_G-M:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=-fOcL8rqkR4:oufe73J_G-M:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=-fOcL8rqkR4:oufe73J_G-M:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/-fOcL8rqkR4" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148426n</guid>




                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 07:53:17 EDT</pubDate>


                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148426n</feedburner:origLink></item>
                    <item>                      
                            <title>Video: Miller on secret surveillance: "This is spying business"</title>

<link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/vFqAAwERzZs/</link>
                        <description>CBS News senior correspondent John Miller, a former deputy director of national intelligence, discusses the federal secret surveillance program and its implications.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=vFqAAwERzZs:A885fr681bQ:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=vFqAAwERzZs:A885fr681bQ:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=vFqAAwERzZs:A885fr681bQ:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=vFqAAwERzZs:A885fr681bQ:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=vFqAAwERzZs:A885fr681bQ:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/vFqAAwERzZs" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148425n</guid>




                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 07:38:15 EDT</pubDate>


                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148425n</feedburner:origLink></item>
                    <item>                      
                            <title>Video: New details revealed about govt.'s secret surveillance</title>
 <link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/XTpjoUk292c/</link>
                        <description>A program called Prism, not only involves phone records of millions of U.S., but the internet as well. The Obama administration's top intelligence official says the program is legal and necessary. Major Garrett reports what has surfaced.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=XTpjoUk292c:mcI5gqhDPjY:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=XTpjoUk292c:mcI5gqhDPjY:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=XTpjoUk292c:mcI5gqhDPjY:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=XTpjoUk292c:mcI5gqhDPjY:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=XTpjoUk292c:mcI5gqhDPjY:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/XTpjoUk292c" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148424n</guid>
                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 07:36:15 EDT</pubDate>
                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148424n</feedburner:origLink></item>
                    <item>
                            <title>Video: Eye Opener: Tropical storm Andrea batters East Coast</title>
                        <link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/dq-HFJaMVzo/</link>
                        <description>Tropical storm Andrea is racing up the East Coast. Also, new information that the government is watching more than your phone calls. Plus, Julian Assange speaks out from political asylum. All that, and all that mattered, in today's "Eye Opener."&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=dq-HFJaMVzo:6LEtjxNyVmA:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=dq-HFJaMVzo:6LEtjxNyVmA:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=dq-HFJaMVzo:6LEtjxNyVmA:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=dq-HFJaMVzo:6LEtjxNyVmA:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=dq-HFJaMVzo:6LEtjxNyVmA:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/dq-HFJaMVzo" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148423n</guid>
                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 07:51:42 EDT</pubDate>
                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148423n</feedburner:origLink></item>
                    <item>
                            <title>Video: Melinda Gates inspires grads to leave their mark with technology</title>                  <link>http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~3/xXfT5uJJ3hg/</link>
                        <description>Melinda Gates and other famous faces made 2013 commencement speeches at universities across the country. They sought to inspire graduates to be good to everyone and follow their civic obligations.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
    &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=xXfT5uJJ3hg:v_JlVdQq0dA:w--LzT5DBIM"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=xXfT5uJJ3hg:v_JlVdQq0dA:w--LzT5DBIM" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=xXfT5uJJ3hg:v_JlVdQq0dA:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.cbsnews.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?a=xXfT5uJJ3hg:v_JlVdQq0dA:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/CBSNewsVideo?i=xXfT5uJJ3hg:v_JlVdQq0dA:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/CBSNewsVideo/~4/xXfT5uJJ3hg" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148399n</guid>
                            <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 08:35:59 EDT</pubDate>
                    <author>Your (optional) podcast author email address (Your (optional) podcast author name)</author><feedburner:origLink>http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=50148399n</feedburner:origLink></item>

            <media:credit role="author">Your (optional) podcast author name</media:credit><media:rating>nonadult</media:rating></channel>
        </rss>
```

Comment: @SatelliteSD i edited

Comment: format the xml please! It is unreadable!

Comment: @SatelliteSD How to format it?

Comment: @Dhasem edit your post, remove emty lines and use 4x " " for intent.

Comment: @Dhasneem are u parse the xml file? are try to read the epub file?have you work on read epub app?i suggest then parse your xml file.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh What is epub app? i didn't.. Prefer any link about that? What is the need of reading that?

Comment: @Dhasneem i advice you get xml response then parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An RSS feed always contains text. This text is separated in several categories, like Title, Description, Author, Publication Date, Link, etc.
Usually, the Description text contains all or part of the main news, while the Link text contains an URL to read the news in the source site.
In the case of CBS news, the Link text contains a link to a page in their site which contains de news video. They could also have put the video embedded in the HTML of the Description text.

There is no safe way to check if an RSS feed contains a video, but you can try at least two things (off the top of my head):
1. Parse the HTML of the Description text to see if there are any embedded video links
2. Download and parse the HTML of the page linked to in the Link text to see if there are any embedded video links

The second option would work for the CBS News feed. However, there are several ways a video can be embedded in an HTML page, and you would need to make your parser look for all of them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Shall you suggest any link to identify the ways for embedding video into HTML?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is an area I'm not very familiar with. @Jan-Ni's comment to his answer should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this..

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml");
 URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
 System.out.println("Content-Type:"+conn.getHeaderField("Content-Type"));
```

Comment: for those two above link I am getting "text/xml". Then how can i identify?

Comment: When I open the above links I get only text.. The video link does not have any video. Kindly check

Answer (score 1):

Yes regarding to earlier answers:
RSS feeds are item lists, in the description of an item you find the HTML code to show (it is escaped HTML code, to emmebeded tags safly in an XML file, so you need to unescape this of course). From my perspective, one could show the description in kind of a webview. But I think this introduces performance problems.
To find out, which external media is hidden, you need obviously to parse the embedded HTML code and there I come to loss of creativity, after following such links you will come to a page with embedded media and with some luck you could grep the video url out of this (mostly it's somehow scrambled afaik)

One strange thing is, I see very often the word "feedburner". Maybe "Videostreams" is a specific feature of one specific Feedreader tool or provider ?

Comment: How videos can be embedded to HTML can be found f.e. here
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp